# How to calculate a point on a rotated axis?

Tags: math, coordinates, angle

How can I calculate a point (X,Y) a specified distance away, on a rotated axis? I know what angle I'd like the point "moving" along (in degrees).

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. There are easy formulae to rotate a point around a specific origin, but I don't see where "a specified distance away" comes into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = cos(a) * d
y = sin(a) * d
```

where a is the angle and d is the distance.

If the trigonometry functions takes radians intead of degrees, you have to convert the angle by dividing by 180/pi.

Comment: Possibly adding "+ox" and "+oy" considering (ox, oy) the origin of the rotation? Or am I wrong on this topic?

Comment: Sure, and a in radians not degrees or grads.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to polar coordinates and then rotate the point through the angle you want:

```
x = r * cos( theta );
y = r * sin( theta );
```

Note: theta in radians ( deg = rad * 180 / pi )

More info on [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the 3d formulas? They are easy as well. But we need to know what's your convention for specifying the axis.